# How can I obtain the domain of a resulting Interpolating Function?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have a problem with obtaining the domain of resulting Interpolating Function in my calculations. I want to solve the following differential equation

```
V[u_, v_] =ProductLog[E^(1/2 (-2 - u + v))]/(1 + ProductLog[E^(1/2 (-2 - u + v))])^4;
sol = First[NDSolve[{-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == V[u, v]* S[u, v], 
S[u, 0] == Exp[-(100/18)], S[0, v] == Exp[-((v - 10)^2/18)]},S, {u,100,200}, {v,100,200},
Method -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> { "TensorProductGrid", 
"MaxStepSize" -> 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 1]]
```

As you can see, I determined the range of `u` and `v` from `100` to `200`, but if you run the code, you will find that the resulting Interpolating Function range will be from `0` to `200` for `v`. How can I fix this problem? Thanks all.

Comment: It seems to be the presence of the statement `S[u, 0] == Exp[-(100/18)]` in your `NDSolve` command that places the lower bound on `v`.  If you change that to `S[u, 10] == ...`, then the interpolating function changes accordingly.  I can't speak to whether this is the intended behavior - it seems to treat the bounds on `u` and `v` differently.

Comment: @JasonB. Actually, `S[u, v] == Exp[-(v - 10)^2/18]` is the boundary condition of the problem which I used `S[u, 0]` and `S[0, v]` in calculations. Can I use `S[u,100] == Exp[-(90)^2/18]` as a new boundary condition to obtain the result that I am looking for?

Comment: Can't you just try the new BCs and see what happens? (I'm pretty sure that the reason for the `v` domain is that in the method of lines, the spatial variable's derivatives are approximated on a spatial grid between the boundaries. `S[u, 0]` specifies one boundary to be `v == 0`. Now why can't `NDSolve` discard all the points outside the specified interval?  I don't know.  I suppose one cannot have an arbitrary boundary coincide with a grid point.  Maybe that's why.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I can. But my laptop is running another code and I cannot do this yet. I just wanted to be sure before that Jason go to sleep, and obviously, I failed and he goes. I must use step grids in my calculation. Considering this constraint, are you saying I cannot adjust the interval of `v`?

Comment: @JasonB. This does not work. When I change the boundary condition, the results change a lot.

Comment: @Mehrab - I'm sorry, my experience with `NDSolve` is minimal.  I don't have any further insight here.

Comment: @Mehrab  Because the boundary conditions are at `u == 0` and `v == 0`, `NDSolve` must integrate to those surfaces, whether or not it includes them in the `InterpolatingFunction`.  That being the case, simply ignore the unwanted part of the `InterpolatingFunction`.  By the way, `"TemporalVariable" -> v` yields a domain of `{{0., 200.}, {100., 200.}}`, and `"TemporalVariable" -> u` yields a domain of `{{100., 200.}, {0., 200.}}`.  But, why worry about this idiosyncrasy?  It does not seem to cause any harm.  Moreover, it is easy enough to trim the domain by postprocessing, if desired.

Comment: @Mehrab  I should add that `AccuracyGoal -> 1` does not yield a very accurate answer.  Just omit this option.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The main code is more complicated than the one is given in the question. I should increase the accuracy in my calculation so I cannot omit it. Indeed, I want to break my main code into smaller ones because it takes a lot of time to be calculated. Therefore, I decided to break the intervals of `u` and `v` into smaller intervals. For example, if `u` goes from `0` to `1000`, I break it into 5 intervals with `[0,200], [200,400], [400,600], [600,800], [800,1000]` in order to take less time to be calculated at each step of these intervals.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Maybe, one can give other suggestions like the answer given below, but it does not solve my problem. My main goal is breaking my code into smaller intervals.

Comment: @Mehrab  The answer below did address your request.  The problem is that you did not request what you actually wanted.  I suggest that you ask a new question that states unambiguously what you desire.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, you are right. I explained the problem for Alexander under his answer and I realized that my problem cannot be solved in this way. I should look for another way. Thanks for your kind effort.

Comment: @Mehrab  You might be able to build a free space Green's Function for this problem, if you introduce variables, `{v - u == x, v + u == t}`, for which `V` depends on `x` only.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Actually, one way to solve such problems is the way that you mentioned, but I did not choose this method. I am working on my thesis and I am running behind, so I do not have time to try other methods. My problem is solved here. I just realized that if I use different intervals, although the resulting interpolating function starts from `v=0` at each interval, it takes less time to be calculated for all intervals compared with the hole interval. For example, calculating a domain from 0 to 200 takes more time compared with two intervals `[0,100]` and `[100,200]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey By the way, I worked in Maple environment for 3 years. 6 months ago, I found out that the Mathematica is more practical and it is much easier to work with. How can I become an expert or good at Mathematica? Do I need to pass some courses? Or I just need to read a book. I will be really thankful if you help.

Comment: Try these two questions for a start.  (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/1063), (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/1063)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider solving the problem in two steps, and then compare for different options `AccuracyGoal`. Below is the code and comparison for the four options `AccuracyGoal`. In Fig. it is clear that the oscillations of the solution are a consequence of the numerical error. These oscillations disappear as the accuracy increases.

```
V[u_, v_] = 
  ProductLog[
    E^(1/2 (-2 - u + v))]/(1 + ProductLog[E^(1/2 (-2 - u + v))])^4;
sol = First[
  NDSolve[{-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == V[u, v]*S[u, v], 
    S[u, 0] == Exp[-(100/18)], S[0, v] == Exp[-((v - 10)^2/18)]}, 
   S, {u, 0, 200}, {v, 0, 200}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxStepSize" -> 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15]]
S0[u_, v_] := S[u, v] /. sol
sol1 = First[
  NDSolve[{-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == V[u, v]*S[u, v], 
    S[u, 100] == S0[u, 100], S[100, v] == S0[100, v]}, 
   S, {u, 100, 200}, {v, 100, 200}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxStepSize" -> 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15]]
{Plot3D[Evaluate[S[u, v] /. sol1], {u, 100, 200}, {v, 100, 200}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> ""], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[S[u, v] /. sol], {u, 100, 200}, {v, 100, 200}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although you answered the question, unfortunately, my problem is still there. For more details please have a look at my comments to Godfrey given above.

Comment: Mehrab, you can not break the 2D region into intervals, you can break the region into subdomains. Thus, there is no benefit of partitioning into intervals, since it is required to specify a function on the boundaries of the domain, and not on the boundaries of the interval.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I should look for a supercomputer for my calculation and there is no other choice.

Comment: A supercomputer is not enough to solve a problem. We need a good algorithm. With a good algorithm, we do not need a supercomputer. I'll see what else can be done in this task.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for your kind effort. How can I become an expert in Mathematica? Do I need to pass some courses? Or I just need to read a book. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Dear Alexander, thanks a lot. My problem is solved here and stop thinking about it. I just realized that if I use different intervals, although the resulting interpolating function starts from `v=0` at each interval, it takes less time to be calculated for all intervals compared with the hole interval. For example, calculating a domain from `0` to `200` takes more time compared with two intervals `[0,100]` and `[100,200]`.